# How do I use default on a hash of empty arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use default to reset my ary when I need to.  But I can't figure out how to not have default's values changed when ary's values change.

```
> default = {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]} 

> ary = default.clone
=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]} 

> ary["a"] << "foo"
=> ["foo"] 

> default
=> {"a"=>["foo"], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: It's basically a list of statistics that are assigned to different states, the states being the keys.  I periodically want to reset the list of statistics but keep all of the states intact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've discovered here is that `Hash#clone` only does a shallow clone, that is it only replicates itself but not the objects that are referenced within it.

There are a number of "deep clone" gems that address this specific problem, or you can write your own to work around it:

```
class Hash
  def deep_clone
    Hash[collect { |k,v| [ k, v.respond_to?(:deep_clone) ? v.deep_clone : v ] }]
  end
end

class Array
  def deep_clone
    collect { |v| v.respond_to?(:deep_clone) ? v.deep_clone : v }
  end
end
```

This will let you clone arbitrary Hash and Array objects as required.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get syntax errors regarding the respond_to?(:clone) statement.

Comment: That just checks if the object in question supports the `deep_clone` method before calling it, as you can't clone things like numbers or `true` and `false` among other things. The only thing you'll need to deep clone in practice is container-type objects.

Answer (score 3):

Both clone and dup create a shallow copy of your object, which results in this behaviour. I'm not sure what the proper way to achieve a deep copy is, but instead of:

```
ary = default.clone
```

Try:

```
ary = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(default))
```

This is taken from a live 2.3.8 environment on ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Marshal can't handle everything you throw at it, so be careful. Plus this has to be one of the most expensive ways to perform this sort of thing.

Comment: Which is why I said I wasn't sure what the proper way to do it was. I like your suggestion as a more case-specific solution, so it got my upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

`clone` only does shallow copies, which is why cloning your hash still keeps everything pointed at the same nested arrays.

You can avoid this through the `Marshal` class by dumping and then loading in the object values:

```
> default = {"a" => [], "b" => [], "c" => []}
=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]} 
> ary = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(default))
=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]} 
> ary["a"] << "foo"
=> ["foo"]
> default
=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Object
  def deep_clone
    Marshal::load(Marshal.dump(self))
  end
end

default = {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
ary = default.deep_clone
ary["a"] << "foo"
default {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
```

Comment: Odd that you would use the `::` notation for one method and `.` for another, but +1 overall.

Comment: That you're able to call methods with `::` always struck me as peculiar and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is as follows:

```
ary = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(default))
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do, a simpler alternative to writing a deep clone method might be to write a method that creates a new default array every time it's called:

```
def default
  {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
end

ary = default #=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}

ary["a"] << "foo" #=> {"a"=>["foo"], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}

default #=> {"a"=>[], "b"=>[], "c"=>[]}
```

Of course, if the contents of your default hash changes over the course of the program this won't work and you'll have to look into the cloning or marshalling techniques, but if the contents are fixed this might be a more straightforward solution.